# Wait doesn't wait for Task completion

Tags: c#

I have console application and executes get stream which takes long time. I added Wait() to wait that, however for some reasons it doesn't wait and immediatly closing console application. From my udnerstanding Wait() should block until task is finished. Can anyone explain me why it not happend. P.S My url get stream takes at least 10 sec therefore now way it finifhes so fast.

```
 class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       new Runner().Run().Wait();
       }
   }

   public class Runner
   {      
       public async Task Run()
       {
          var hc = new HttpClient();
          await hc.GetStreamAsync("whateverURLwhichtakeslongtime");
       }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't valid C#, I assume your `new Runner...` is in the `Main` method? Is your `Main` marked `async`? You can do that, depending on the C# version you are compiling against, then you just call `await new Runner().Run(...);`

Comment: `message As Message`, `await new Email()`? Is that supposed to be pseudo-code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: There are also executable statements outside of a method, methods outside any class.  It's definitely not compile-ready.

Comment: Where is your main method though ?

Comment: `public static Main()` does not compile. Please read how to and post a [mcve]

Comment: How does `await new Email();` compile for you? `await` can only be applied to `Task` and `Task<T>`

Comment: Now, the only thing missing is the implementation of `MailNotificationChannel.Send`, or is that some library?

Comment: `MailNotificationChannel.Send` could be returning an already completed Task. As Camilo has asked, do you know how that method is implemented?

Comment: Modified once again to make it simpler.

Comment: `new Runner().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: @Luminous_Dev i assume it make await internallyhowever why Wait() doesnt wait?

Answer (score 1):

Code seem fine to me when I tested it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1");
        new Runner().Run().Wait();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("4");
    }
}

public class Runner
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var hc = new HttpClient();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2");
        var result = await hc.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3");
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
<!doctype html>......some long google page response
3
4
```

So it actually works fine.

**Now if this isnt clear then try with Thread.Sleep(5000) // sleep for 5 second
the main is definitly waiting**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1");
        new Runner().Run().Wait();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("4");
    }
}

public class Runner
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var hc = new HttpClient();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3");
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
...waiting 5 seconds
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, when you call `.Wait()` (or `.Result`) on an incomplete task, all bets are off; that simply isn't a well-defined scenario. Fortunately, recent C# versions include `async` support for entry-points, so: use it!

```
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       await new Runner().Run();
   }
```

This *could* also be simplified in this case to:

```
   static Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       return new Runner().Run();
   }
```